# C# DateTimePicker Custom Format

Tags: c#, button

How do I set a DateTimePicker to out put dd/mm/yyyy.

At the moment it is giving me the day, date, month then year.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using a Windows Application form, if I make the 'DatePicker' like this: "DatePicker.FormatCustom" it doesnt work...

Comment: it's CustomFormat not FormatCustom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property [`DateTimePicker.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx) to [`DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepickerformat.aspx) and set your desired format in the [`DateTimePicker.CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
        dtpDeliveryDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtpDeliveryDate.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```